# Find the integral $\int_{-2}^{1} |x| d |x|$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

To handle the integral $\int_{-2}^{1} |x| d |x|$ I do not see a way to begin with.

If instead I am to compute $\int_{-2}^{1} |x| dx$ then things get easier, for simply computing $\int_{0}^{1} x dx + \int_{0}^{2} x dx$ suffices.

Comment: don't we have $$\int \clubsuit \; d\clubsuit = \dfrac{\clubsuit^2}{2} + C$$ ?

Comment: Yeah, my problem is that I am not sure how to deal with $d|x|$? You mean $d|x|$ doesn ot matter here?

Comment: @Chou Replace $\clubsuit$ with $|x|$ in your calculation.

Comment: Oh? If so then what is the primitive $\int |x| dx$? Thanks.

Comment: Is $d|x|$ even well defined here? I was under the assumption that this notation was reserved for the R-S integrals which require the function $|x|$ to be non-decreasing, which it does not satisfy in this case.

Comment: The most straightforward way to integrate this function is to split the domain accordingly where x < 0 gives -x in the that integrand and  $x\geq 0$ gives x in the integrand. You then add the results of both integrals. It turns out in this case it's even easier then that because  where x < 0, both x and dx are negative,which  yields a positive integrand when you multiply the 2 -1's.  Simple.

Comment: @MatthewLevy There is no requirement for being no-decreasing, but you might need bounded-variations (which would mean it is the difference of two non-decreasing functions.) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Existence_of_the_integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this

> $$ \int_{-2}^{1}|x|d|x| = \int_{-2}^{0}(-x)d(-x) + \int_{0}^{1}(x)\,d(x) = \int_{-2}^{0}x\,dx + \int_{0}^{1}x\,d x = \int_{-2}^{1} x \,dx$$

$$ = \dots\,. $$

Comment: There you go,bingo.Not difficult if you understand what |x|  means.

Comment: Rather, if you understand what $\int f(x)dg(x)$, a Riemann-Stieljes integral.